# The customization cannot be run because the solution ID in the document does not match

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto

I have developed a VSTO solution for Excel 2010 in VS 2010. The target framework is .NET 3.5. The solution works fine if I have all the components (dll, vsto and manifest and the Excel file) in one folder. I open the Excel file and the add-ins loads perfectly well.

However, when I tried creating the MSI where all the components (except the Excel file) would be installed in a specified folder and the user can download the Excel file and save in any location. Then its failing with the following error message:

**Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.InstallAddInFailedException: The customization cannot be installed because the solution ID in the document does not match the customization. Contact your administrator for further assistance.**

I have tried many options and searched on net but nothing found.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you develop a document level add-in? If so, you need to include the Excel file into the installer package.

Make sure that you did all the steps described in the [Publishing an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.